# External javascript not loading in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to load a custom js file on wordpress, I've upload to my javascript theme folder and I'm using the following code in functions.php but I can't make it work:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('service-graph', plugins_url('js/service-graph.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('service-graph');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **get_template_directory_uri()** function for get the theme folder path.then you can pass js/yourjsfile path name.

Try below code

```
<?php

    function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('service-graph', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/service-graph.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('service-graph');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
    ?>
```

Jfyi - if you put anything in your current active theme folder you must need to use **[get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)** function as its return path to your theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a wrong function to retrieve theme's folder.

[`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) is used for plugins, as you could guess from its name. It means that it would point to `/wp-content/plugins` directory, which is not where your theme is located.

You need to use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) instead. Note that this function does not return a trailing slash `/` following the directory address, so you need to add it to the beginning of your path.

So here's how your code should look like:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('service-graph', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/service-graph.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('service-graph');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```